# Latex: проблемы с компиляцией

Tags: компиляция, latex

Новый ноут, редактор gummi. Ни один из теховских файлов с русским языком  не читается.
Проблема уже в начале.

Вот мой стандартный заголовок (спокойно работает на старом ноуте, у других людей и в онлайн latex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[cm,empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}    % Картинки
\usepackage{cmap}
```

А вот то, что отвечает gummi:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/limprop/Загрузки/.18-03-03.tex.swp
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 4 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:100: Font T1/cmr/m/n/1
2=ecrm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:100:  ==> Fatal error 
occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /tmp/.18-03-03.tex.log
```

Гугл советовал скачать textlive-latex-recommended, я не нашла этот пакет.

Как можно починить?

Comment: В общем, я проверил преамбулу в TeXLive 2013 на Xubuntu 14.04. при установке TeXLive по-умолчанию пришлось добавить пакет texlive-lang-cyrrillic. После этого документ нормально откомпилировался. Нужно смотреть, что из пакетов у Вас не установилось, а лучше, установить мета-пакет texlive-full.
И небольшое замечание по самой преамбуле. Как я и подозревал, пакет babel автоматически загружает `fontenc` с нужными параметрами, поэтому явно указывать fontenc не нужно. Пакет `cmap` должен быть загружен до fontenc, а соответственно и до babel.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что поможет, но...

Tex ругается на:

> Font T1/cmr/m/n/12=ecrm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file
>   not found

В моём шаблоне для Тех-а за включением пакета

```
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

сразу стоит включение

```
\usepackage[LGR,T2A]{fontenc}
```

Где-то слышал, что Т2 - современный вариант Т1...

Comment: Не совсем так. Дело не в современности. Внутренние кодировки TeX  T1/OT1 и т.п. - насколько я помню, соответствуют европейскому набору символов. Кириллический набор символов T2 (причем, русская кириллица - T2A).

Comment: Я в этих настройках не разбираюсь абсолютно, чисто как пользователь работаю, просто посмотрел, что у меня стоит в шаблоне, с которого я начинаю набор всех текстов.

Comment: Если исправить Т1 на Т2 или Т2А, отвечает
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:99: Package fontenc Er
ror: Encoding file `t2enc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.

See the fontenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                               
l.99 \ProcessOptions*                    
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:99:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: Короче, тоже не нравится. Странно, что онлайновый тех спокойно эти заголовки глотает и даже не дергается.

Comment: @ЖеняФофанова, а Вы не пробовали вообще убрать этот пакет (fontenc)? Я его обычно вообще не использую. Правда, при этом у меня кодировка файла не utf8, а cp1251... Но не думаю, что это должно влиять. Возможно, у Вас не установлен пакет с русскими шрифтами. Что у Вас за линух? - наверное, надо оценить, что у него в пакетной базе есть... И как Вы устанавливали texlive? Проверил: у меня в MikTeX под win7 Ваш заголовок нормально отработал, без ошибок. Значит вопрос в недоустановленных пакетах.

Comment: Я уже помню туманно, но когда я только запускал у себя на компе ТеХ, то тогда заходил на некий сайт - центральное хранилище пакетов и там была инструкция - как эти пакеты устанавливать. Я тогда много пакетов устанавливал дополнительно. К сожалению, ничего не записал., а сейчас уже не помню :-(

Comment: @Sergey, скорее всего то было одно из зеркал CTAN, но обычно он не нужен. Если брать современный полный дистрибутив под windows (texlive или miktex), то там уже есть все необходимые пакеты. С линуксом немножко сложнее - там в зависимости от дистрибутива, обычно устанавливается не вся подсистема tex и нужно до-устанавливать через системный пакетный менеджер.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, разобралась. Не хватало одного пакета, плюс Т2А, а не Т1.

Comment: @Vladimir , этот пакет проблем не вызывал, как ни странно (: